# How can I get the matrix for these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables here and need to produce a matrix for all combinations

Table 1

```
Brand Company ID
1     1       1 
2     2       2
3     3       3
```

Table 2

```
Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 Prod4 Prod5 
4     5     6     18    19
5     6     7     20    5
```

The result I'm trying to achieve

Result table:

```
Brand Company ID Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 Prod4 Prod5 
1     1       1   4     5     6     18    19
1     1       1   5     6     7     20    5
2     2       2   4     5     6     18    19
2     2       2   5     6     7     20    5
```

I could have worked with this if they have some kind of ID just not to how to approach this to get the matrix.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what happened to the third row from `table1` in your query and why it isn't in the result, but I think you are looking for a `cross join`.

```
select Brand, Company, ID, Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4, Prod5 
from table1
  cross join table2
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UOZ33372

returns (with added `order by`):

```
+-------+---------+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Brand | Company | ID | Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 | Prod4 | Prod5 |
+-------+---------+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |       1 |  1 |     4 |     5 |     6 |    18 |    19 |
|     1 |       1 |  1 |     5 |     6 |     7 |    20 |     5 |
|     2 |       2 |  2 |     4 |     5 |     6 |    18 |    19 |
|     2 |       2 |  2 |     5 |     6 |     7 |    20 |     5 |
|     3 |       3 |  3 |     4 |     5 |     6 |    18 |    19 |
|     3 |       3 |  3 |     5 |     6 |     7 |    20 |     5 |
+-------+---------+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for CROSS JOIN, thank you ! Appreciate it